# Remove Pointer and # from admin grid Magento 2

Tags: adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, magento2.2.2

I am using Magento 2.2.2. I created admin grid using UI Component. 
When I hover on the row fields, its showing pointer(Hand Symbol) and # tag.

How to remove it??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in the layout xml file for admin, ie., `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/frontname_controller_action.xml`.

Add this code in the `<block>` tag.

```
<arguments>
  <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="path" xsi:type="string"></item>
  </argument>
```